# How to run a shell script as different user with PHP on Nginx?

Tags: php, bash, shell, nginx

Trying to trigger a shell script with POST request (handled by nginx). No success so far.

What I have:

```
exec('whoami'); // nginx

nginx:x:220:498:Nginx web server:/var/lib/nginx:/sbin/nologin
```

As we can see, nginx user has no shell. Could that be a problem? Next,

```
nginx ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

If I change `nginx` to my real user, I can run `sudo -u user /path/to/script.sh` without password prompt, but for some reason I'm still asked for password if I run `su -s /bin/bash -c /path/to/script.sh user`. Perhaps, latter invokation is somewhat more suitable for the `nginx` user, since he has `nologin` shell.

So whenever I run `exec('sudo -u user /path/to/script.sh');` or run some wrapper script with that line in it through PHP - nothing happens. I can't even identify what doesn't work, since no errors are thrown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command to get back the error output. Also if you want to execute `/bin/bash`, you need that as an entry in the `sudoers` file. Alternatively you might want to create a wrapper script that `nginx` can simply execute and that can handle the `sudo` if it's suitable for your needs

Comment: Adding `nginx` to `sudoers` only grants it `sudo` privileges, not `su`.  The two are related, in that they perform similar purposes, but nevertheless separate.  Historically, `sudo` is a wrapper for `su` with additional usability features and access control mechanisms.

Comment: "No errors are thrown" is incorrect; you should find an error message in your system logs.  Traditionally, `sudo` errors are logged to `auth.log` which on modern LSB systems lives in `/var/log`.  (Now let's hope you have read access :-)

Comment: Wow, @fejese, thanks for the `2>&1`. Now it immediately says `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. Yes, I've already tried the wrapper script, which did exactly the same thing `sudo -u ...`, but, now, since I have errors showing, I can dig further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the @fejese and @triplee , I finally figured it out. I had to `requiretty` parameter in sudoers file, when that was changed to...

```
#Defaults   requiretty
#Defaults   !visiblepw
```

...it all went going!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer! :) Now I just have to say that its funny that your question answered my question! haha